# How to extract specific content using pandas and get android version

Tags: python, regex

Consider the following data

```
Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)
Android 4.4.2 (KitKat)
Android 4.0.3 (Ice Cream Sandwich)
Android 2.3.5 (Gingerbread)
```

I wanted just the version number only like below

```
6.0
4.4.2`
4.0.3
2.3.5
```

so i tried this

```
^\D*(\d+)
```

this would return the part just before the period is there any other to do this

Comment: If you don't know regex, learn them! But you can also use `split(".")`, you know...

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
\d.\d.(\d{0,})
```

Tip: I find https://www.regexpal.com/ very helpful to quickly test various regex strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know regex, you *really* should read a tutorial on them. You'll probably find them useful again and again!

Here, I would suggest this: `Android\s+(\d+)(\.\d+)+\s` because it is *conservative*, and unlikely to produce false matches.

If you don't want to learn regex, try doing the same with `split(".")` etc. I wouldn't be surprised if `line.split(".")[0].split(" ")[-1]` works for you most of the time...